# One of my scratch org environments suddenly expired. Is there a way to renew expired scratch org or at least renew the expired data?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin, dev-hub

Just already passed 30 days from the creation my scratch org
Is there a way to rescue that scratch org or at least (in the future) to extend the time for above 30 days or to create a copy of that scratch org to contain all the changes?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Salesforce deletes scratch Orgs and their associated ActiveScratchOrg records from your Dev Hub org when a scratch org expires.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm),

> After the scratch org has expired, you can’t restore it.

Unfortunately,even Salesforce support will also not be able to help in this scenario.

Comment: Also see this [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213251/restore-an-expired-scratch-org#)